# Why is capturing the bishop in this position a blunder?

Tags: sicilian-defense, middlegame

```
[FEN "r2n1rk1/pp1bppbp/1n4p1/q1N5/3P3N/PB2B2P/1P3PP1/R2Q1RK1 w - - 3 18"]
```

Why is Nxd7 a blunder in this position?

I think that once the light squared bishop comes to c6 it will become very strong and hence removing it should be a good move, but according to Stockfish after Nxd7 the evaluation drops from around +4 to +0.6.

Comment: What move does it suggest to let the position stay at +4 evaluation?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is a blunder because White can **win a piece** instead. The Black queen is in a molasses of its own pieces, and White has a very good chance of trapping it. Capturing the bishop loses this chance, making the move a mistake.

Here is White's best line of play that quickly plants Black a firm loss.

```
[FEN "r2n1rk1/pp1bppbp/1n4p1/q1N5/3P3N/PB2B2P/1P3PP1/R2Q1RK1 w - - 0 1"]

1. a4 Qb4 2. a5
```

By playing a4, White threatens to play Bd2 on the next move, winning the Black queen. Moving the Black knight on b6 to clear room for the queen doesn't help. This is because moving it will lose the bishop on d7, which is attacked by the White knight on c5. As such, Black's best move is Qb4. Now White can play a5 and win a piece. Either the Black knight is taken by the pawn, or it moves, and the bishop is lost.

In other words, playing **Nxd7 is a blunder** because the **chance to win a piece**, and likely the game as a result, **is lost.** This teaches that it is very important to look out for any threats that you can make.